# División entre dos consultas distintas

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Tengo estas dos consultas. Esta es la primera:

```
SELECT SUM ("Asignatura"."UndCreditoAsignatura") as "UNIDADES INSCRITAS"
FROM 
  public."ExpedienteAcademico", 
  public."Asignatura"
WHERE 
  "ExpedienteAcademico"."idAsignatura" = "Asignatura"."idAsignatura"
  and "Nota" is not null
  and "idTipoNota" in (1,2)
```

Y esta:

```
SELECT SUM ("Asignatura"."UndCreditoAsignatura") as "UNIDADES APROBADAS"
FROM 
  public."ExpedienteAcademico", 
  public."Asignatura"
WHERE 
  "ExpedienteAcademico"."idAsignatura" = "Asignatura"."idAsignatura"
  and "Nota" >= 10 
  and "Nota" is not null
  and "idTipoNota" in (1,2)
  and "AprobadoPorEquivalencia" = 'N'
```

Básicamente lo que necesito es dividir el resultado de la consulta de "Unidades Aprobadas" entre la que arroja "Unidades Inscritas" y ese resultado debo denominarlo "Eficiencia Académica". Realmente tengo la duda, porque si se fijan es la misma tabla donde hago las operaciones, pero en la segunda consulta que pongo hay unos condicionales que no se encuentran colocados en la primera. De allí surge mi inquietud.

Agradecería a quienes puedan ayudarme con esto. Mil gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptualmente es correcto lo que te piden.
La eficiencia la miden como cuantos cumplen con la condición (los apbrobados) dividido el universo (los inscriptos).
El resultado es un valor entre 0 y 1, que multiplicado por 100 te dará el porcentaje.

Para hacer la consulta podes utilizar estos dos queries como subqueries de la división.
Si entendí bien, cada query te da un solo número como resultado, si el resultado tuviera que estar abierto por materia o algún otro concepto habría que agregarle a los subquerie una "clave" ficticia para atar los resultados en el query final.

```
select cast(t2.aprobados as decimal) / cast(t1.inscriptos as decimal) 
from (
    SELECT SUM ("Asignatura"."UndCreditoAsignatura") as inscriptos
    FROM 
      public."ExpedienteAcademico", 
      public."Asignatura"
    WHERE 
      "ExpedienteAcademico"."idAsignatura" = "Asignatura"."idAsignatura"
      and "Nota" is not null
      and "idTipoNota" in (1,2)
) as t1,
(
    SELECT SUM ("Asignatura"."UndCreditoAsignatura") as aprobados
    FROM 
      public."ExpedienteAcademico", 
      public."Asignatura"
    WHERE 
      "ExpedienteAcademico"."idAsignatura" = "Asignatura"."idAsignatura"
      and "Nota" >= 10 
      and "Nota" is not null
      and "idTipoNota" in (1,2)
      and "AprobadoPorEquivalencia" = 'N'
) as t2;
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por responder.

Quedé muy clara con tu respuesta. Ahora bien, tengo una duda. Por qué el valor me arroja 0 nada más? Si realizo la división de la cantidad de unidades aprobadas (115) entre la cantidad de unidades inscritas (198) me debería mostrar como resultado 0.5808 y no 0 nada más.

¿Qué me faltaría por hacer para que muestre el resultado completo?

Comment: Eso es porque los valores son enteros y al dividir trunca los decimales. Supuestamente con hacer un cast de alguno de los operadores a decimal, ya tenes que ver el resultado condecimales. Edité la respuesta e hice el cast de ambos numeros.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, de verdad que me resultó de gran ayuda todo lo que me explicaste acá.